# Cannot lock all files in directory using SVN

Tags: svn

Is there an easy way to lock all files in directory for svn. As I know we cannot lock all directory?

Comment: SVN system does not recommend locking at all, let alone locking whole directories. Why is locking needed for you?

Comment: I'm not going to commit this . I just need to do some testing

Comment: If you are not going to commit, then why is locking files (on the server side?) of any importance?

Comment: I need to lock all files in my working copy

Comment: We understand that you need to do it, but we are wondering *why* do you need to do it. Maybe your answer can help us help you so that you don't actually have to use locks.

Comment: during svn checkout sometimes I have the following error

    svn working copy '.' locked try performing 'cleanup'


So I want to test if svn cleanup will take much time. That is why I want to lock all files and perform svn cleanup

Comment: This error informs you that the repository is locked, even though it should not be locked. This usually means that some operation did not finish properly. You don't have to lock folders in the repository. The word "lock" is used here in two different ways. Just "perform cleanup" without locking the folder and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock a folder hierarchy **on the server side** by committing an svn property like this:

```
svn propset lock TRUE trunk/project/folder
svn commit -m "Files locked for debugging" trunk/project/folder
```

You can release the lock using `svn propdel`.

Comment: I think you are referring to this article [SVN Directory Lock](http://www.noah.org/wiki/SVN_Directory_Lock) but you forgot to mention one important detail: **It requires to install a pre-commit hook script on the server.**

Answer (score 0):

In source repository, contents are stored in files, directory(Folder) is a structure/Path to actual contents/files. if you rename any directory, you can understand more on this.

Generally, folder/directory is a collection of files.

So if you want to lock a root folder, then you follow given procedure.
1. Select the root directory you wish to lock, then perform right click
2. Then click TortoiseSVN->GetLock..., so dialog will be displayed with all available files under the directory you selected, including  files under child directory.

You can select whatever files you wish to lock, Please not Locking file means, you are locking the content in path specified.